# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" (using in sproc/package/job)

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I get this message when trying to run a SSIS package that uses OpenRowSet to extract data from Excel files using OLEDB.

I tried a number of different solutions mentioned on StackOverflow - including:

- reinstalling the OLEDB drivers
- checking access to the temp folders (I changed the temp folder system variables to be a specific folder rather than dynamic by username + gave access to Everyone to that folder)
- checking execution of the OpenRowSet query in a query window/executing a sproc that uses it/executing a package referencing the sproc/executing a job that refers to the above package - in my situation I could get the query to run directly as a query I opened SSMS as administrator only.

I could repro the issue in our PRD environment (we haven't launched yet so PRD is effectively a test environment) but not on our STG environment. I did a schema compare to make sure the codebase was the same across environments.

We used the oledb.12 driver (rather than oledb.16) and use the driver to get metadata and then to import the actual records.

Answer that helped me (I couldn't find anywhere online...) is below

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found that I needed to change the local windows user group membership.

The sql server agent job runs using a proxy, which uses a credential, which refers to a windows account.

In our case, the STG windows account was part of Administrator, but on PRD it was only in Users (this is why schema compare showed no difference at the SQL level - it was a windows OS issue).

Despite the fact that the error refers to the oledb driver, and we had given access to all to TMP/TEMP and the file location, we needed to change the user access in Computer Management to fix the issue.

It's taken 2 of us 3 days to fix this issue so hopefully this helps someone out there!